# Flask CORS not working with Nginx in production but working on local without nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

I currently have an issue where I have set up a flask app with

```
CORS(app)
```

But I get every sort of COR's error as a response.  This only happens in production though.
I get errors like

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' from origin 'https://2e11e606fda6.ngrok.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Or

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' from origin 'https://2e11e606fda6.ngrok.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed
```

I also tried diferent variations of CORS requests in the headers via nginx `location /` block, but that lead to some of the same sort of errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple hours of exhausting everything.  I by chance ended up looking in the nginx access log.

There it showed a error code 413

From there I was able to fix my nginx config to allow the file upload to work.  So it seems that the CORS issue is not always actually about cors, but the way nginx reports errores.

Comment: CORS are a tricky thing, specially in Flask. If a traceback occurs, the Flask-CORS request handler may not be called and the headers will not be added. In production it may be useful to add CORS headers through NGINX, take a look at this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/176729